# How to create a TSVECTOR column in a materialized view?

Tags: postgresql, index, full-text-search, materialized-view

I am trying to implement full text search in a materialized view (MV for brevity), and I read that it's not possible to alter the MV itself, which rules out these solutions:

1. Adding a new column with a specific data type after the MV has been created.
2. Creating the MV with an empty column and change the column data type.

I tried both and well yes, as expected it doesn't work.

So my idea was to add a cast on the empty column when creating the MV:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv AS 
  SELECT id, '' AS textsearchable_index_col::tsvector
  FROM tbl
  ...
WITH NO DATA
```

But it returns the following error:

> `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "::"`

How can I achieve this?

ps: I am willing to have a column instead of an index because I'd like to use weighing.

**Additional information**

I am able to have the column created like so:

```
 CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv AS 
   SELECT id, CAST ('' AS tsvector) AS textsearchable_index_col
   FROM tbl
   ...
 WITH NO DATA
```

However I can't update the column using:

```
UPDATE mv SET textsearchable_index_col = to_tsvector('english', coalesce(title,''))
```

I get  an error:

> `ERROR:  cannot change materialized view "mv"`

Comment: 'doesn't work' is not really a description that explains your problem.  How exactly it doesn't work?

Comment: @dezso Edited question.

Comment: Why don't you drop the materialized view and recreate it in a transaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you drop the materialized view ,and recreate it in a transaction? You can't update a materialized view. They're a view that's been written to disk.

Instead of

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv AS 
   SELECT id, CAST ('' AS tsvector) AS textsearchable_index_col
   FROM tbl
[...]
UPDATE mv SET textsearchable_index_col = to_tsvector('english', coalesce(title,''))
```

Just do

```
BEGIN;
  DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW IF EXISTS mv;
  CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv AS 
     SELECT
       id,
       textsearchable_index_col = to_tsvector('english', coalesce(title,''))
     FROM tbl
COMMIT;
```

You don't have to have a materialized view for this though, yo can create a functional index which will work on the table directly

```
CREATE INDEX ON tbl USING GIN (to_tsvector('english', title));
```

Or, just use the default cast..

```
CREATE INDEX ON tbl USING GIN ((title::tsvector));
```

And then depending, on your index condition,

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE 'foo & bar' @@ to_tsvector('english', title);

SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE 'foo & bar' @@ title::tsvector;
```

Comment: Thanks, for your help. I can drop the MV without problem and recreate it. However I can't update a column based index. If I go with the regular GIN index, I am afraid there isn't a way to apply weights to columns. Am I right ?

Comment: @Stanislasdrg you can apply weights, but you need a unique index for every possible combination of weights. `USING GIN ( SETWEIGHT(to_tsvector())||SETWEIGHT(to_tsvector())||SETWEIGHT(to_tsvector()))` then be sure to use that same condition in your query.